# 2 year old toddler closes her eyes only in the classroom in school

Tags: toddler, behavior, daycare, eyes

Our 2 year old closes her eyes in the classroom in school, and only opens them when she steps outside the classroom to go to the playground or toilet. She has been there for 3 weeks, and I'm wondering if this is normal.

She still eats, plays and participates, just with her eyes closed when in the classroom. When the teacher tried bringing her outside the corridor of the classroom, she would open her eyes and do the activities. I'm not sure what's wrong, is anyway we can help her?

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if there's something about the light in the classroom that's bothering her?  If so, maybe a baseball cap would help.  Can you ask her in a very gentle way why she prefers to close her eyes in the classroom?

I'm not sure what country you're in, but in some (many?) countries, you can ask the school to evaluate her.  It might be good to include Occupational Therapy and Vision in the evaluation.

Often, bringing a concern to a primary care provider is a good starting point.